# Symfony2+Twig, variable in translation return "A message must be a simple text"

Tags: php, symfony, twig

When I was doing plain PHP, I was simply doing this:

```
printf(_("Hello %s !"), $name);
```

Now with Twig, I must use the trans tag. So I've copy/paste the [documentation example](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/i18n.html), and here's my full template:

```
{% extends 'MyAppBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>
        {% trans %}
            Hello {{ name }}!
        {% endtrans %}
    </h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Why Symfony return the following exeption ?

> A message must be a simple text in "MyAppBundle::home.html.twig"
>
> 500 Internal Server Error - Twig_Error_Syntax

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The precise syntax for translations is a little different in Symfony2 than it is in standalone Twig. You'll want to check out the Symfony2 documentation for translations in twig templates, found [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#twig-templates). The correct syntax would look something like this:

```
{% trans %}Hello %name%!{% endtrans %}
```

Comment: Hey thanks ! I've also found this syntax: {{ 'welcome.message'|trans({'%titre%':name}) }}

Answer (score 21):

One missing bit with the previous answer is the "with" portion that is needed to do the replacement of the variable part of the message.

```
{% trans with {'%name%':name} %}Hello %name%!{% endtrans %}
```

Comment: This should be the selected answer

Comment: According to current docs there's no need to use the `with` part, see http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#twig-templates

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue: to pass my translation path to `trans` filter, I need to concatenate a string and a variable, then transform into lowercase.

Here `{% trans %}` and `{% endtrans %}` are not used, but `trans` filter instead:

```
<span>{{ ('statuses.' ~ status | lower) | trans }}</span>
```

Assuming in the translation there is:

```
- status:
  - failed: The task has failed
```

and in the template you pass the variable `name` with value `FAILED`.