# Symfony2 presenting an array value as a translated text

Tags: symfony, twig

it does not seem possible to use a value i am getting right from an array, as a translated text....so when i have

```
{% for key,value in ratings %}

<th scope="row">
   {% trans %}
    {{ value.type }}
    {% endtrans %}</th>
<td ><div  class="rating" id= "{{ value.type }}"   data-rating="{{ value.ratingaverage }}"
           thread="{{thread_id}}" rating_readonly= "{{ value.readOnly }}" route="{{ path('addrating') }}"  ></div> </td>
{% endfor %}
```

i get the error

```
A message must be a simple text in TrackerMembersBundle::rating.html.twig at line 92
```

what is meant here, is the line with

```
     {% trans %}
    {{ value.type }}
    {% endtrans %}
```

i cannot seem to be able to use trans upon the value coming directly from array? the value would be for example `"file.quality"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps its better when you search here before.

[Symfony2+Twig, variable in translation return "A message must be a simple text"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811162/symfony2twig-variable-in-translation-return-a-message-must-be-a-simple-text)

The mistake is the variable in the translation block. You have to set an placeholder and replace this with a value.

```
{% trans with {'%type%':value.type} %}
    This is my %type%!
{% endtrans %}
```

Comment: The search bar on top or google the first choice was the solution here on Stackoverflow ;)