# Symfony forcing translation into different language than the current one

Tags: symfony, twig, translation

I have the locale set to one language. Let's say german "de" and I want to have **a part of the whole text** translated into different languages (Ex. **This happened 100 years ago -> This happened vor 100 Jahre**). For this I am trying the following code:

```
//this returns 'site.dates.years'
{% set yearsText = yearsCount|displayTimeDivisions() %} 

( {{ yearsCount }} {% trans with {'%content%': yearsText } from "messages" into "en" %}%content%{% endtrans %}
```

after using the `trans` method i get the string from `yearsText` ('site.dates.years') and not the translated content. Is this even possible to translate or I should drop it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works as expected, what you are trying to translate is `%content%`, not `site.dates.years`. Try this:

```
//this returns 'site.dates.years'
{% set yearsText = yearsCount|displayTimeDivisions() %} 

( {{ yearsCount }} {% trans from "messages" into "en" %}{{ yearsText }}{% endtrans %}
```

**Edit**
The previous suggestion doesn't work as using `trans` in that way only works with simple text, not with variables.

This works for me:

```
{{ yearsText | trans({}, 'messages', 'en') }}
```

Comment: Thanks Nicolae but if I am doing that I get another error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811162/symfony2twig-variable-in-translation-return-a-message-must-be-a-simple-text that's why I asked the question... something is fishy here

Comment: a bit nasty, but what if you do it like this (I haven't tested it myself):
`{% trans with {} from "messages" into "en" %}{{ yearsText }}{% endtrans %}`

Comment: Just tested it, the above doesn't work with dynamic values apparently.

Comment: I just edited my response. Give it a try and let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: a bit confusing ... but this is the right answer! Thanks Nicolae!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** clear cache

Sometimes Symfony has a too strong caching mechanism. If you work without locales first, and then modify controllers and twigs to be multi-locale and you also add a new messages file, Symfony loads all new controller/twigs but somehow misses that there are new message files. A simple cache clear, done ONLY ONCE (!) right after you add the message files, solves this problem. And thenceforth you don't need to clear the cache every time you change a translation.

Try this as a last resort. If this doesn't help I'd recommend to read carefully the documentation (link in the last line of this answer):

```
app/console cache:clear --env=dev
```

---

You may try one or all (!) of these, it's impossible to tell what is going wrong.

```
{{ yearsCount|trans }}
{{ 'site.dates.years'|trans }}
```

See if these translate. If the second does, you're setting the variable wrong, somehow.

If not, pass the `_locale` along in the route:

```
defaults: { _controller: Bundle:Controller:action, _locale: de }
```

Or have it as a route parameter:

```
path: /a/path/{_locale}/whatever
  defaults: { _controller: Bundle:Controller:action }
  requirements:
      _locale: en|de
```

Print the locale to be sure it's properly set in the twig:

```
{{ app.request.locale }}
{{ app.request.getLocale() }}
```

If the locale prints out fine but the translation still does not work, it's because Symfony does not find the identifier. Go to the translations file and check that it's written correctly:

```
site:
  dates:
    years: Jahre
```

If you find it in `messages.de.yml` then maybe it's the wrong placement of the file. The loader searches for these files:

> Symfony looks for message files (i.e. translations) in the following default locations:
>
> - the app/Resources/translations directory;
> - the app/Resources/MyAppBundle/translations directory;
> - the Resources/translations/ directory inside of any bundle.

If fiddling around with these files doesn't yield results, it's a configuration error in `config.yml`, or many overlapping errors (all of the above?) that work against you.

Here's the source of all pain/info about translations, but you've probably memorized every paragraph, by now: [Symfony translations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The simple {{ 'text'|trans }} is working properly. but in the current locale ('de'). But when I am trying to force it into a different language then the issue arrives...

Comment: And what about `{{ _locale }}`? does this print in DE and EN? or just DE?

Comment: {{ _locale }} is not defined as this is defined in the cookies at user login based on his selected language.

Comment: You're right, I made an error there. Look at the corrected answer (`app.request.locale`).

Comment: yep. this is `de` the current language selected by the user. Also thing is that I cannot force a route with the locale .. this has to be done dynamic somehow like that option in trans `into "language"`

Comment: Normally you use a parameterized route like the one shown above where the path is like `/before/{locale}/after/`. It's a good thing that a user can switch language at any time with a language selector or by editing the URL directly. I've never used a cookies, preferring expressive routes instead. I think the problem must lie in the `messages.*.yml` files. Also, see the last edit I'm doing above. If this doesn't help I don't know any further!